# How to make a thread return arraylist of objects in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I want a thread to return list. I cant use the run method as its return type is void. I am using the thread in a separate private method inside a class under which the caller method of the thread is also there. The caller needs the list from thread result to do some manipulation. here is my thread. Pls help me in understanding how can i return list from this thread.

```
private List<myObject> fetchmyObjList(final String abc){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    List<myObject> myObjList = anotherInternalMethod(abc);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e);

                    }
                }


        }).start();



    }
```

how can i make this thread return myObjList to the caller?? Please help.

Answer (score 6):

You need [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead of Runnable.

Here is an how-to-use callable: https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6

Answer (score 1):

Use callable instead of Runnable. The function is capable of returning a value in the form of Futures. You can utilize this to achieve your own purpose.

Comment: Why the name Futures for the value returned?

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic the name Future is because the execution is asynchronous and the result will be available in the Future.

Answer (score 0):

You can push your data to external object (like object which have fetchmyObjList) using just a method like:

```
List<myObject> myObjList = anotherInternalMethod(abc);
setFetchedObjects(myObjList);
```

This is a scenerio when you puts controll to newly created thread. We can call it simplivied observer pattern - outer object is notified by method call when data is available. But remember about thread safety in this scenerio!

Other scenerio is to use `Callable<OBJECT YOU WANT TO RETURN>` and use a Thread/ExecutorService to start your task. Then (in control in your outer object) you can use Callable `.get()` to get your result.
You cen use blocking or nonblocking methods to wait for result or to check if result is ready to receive from background task.

Of course in your scenerio, creating a Thread with Callable just to block original thread and wait to task completion to return your objects from method, gives nothing - it would be better to not use threads at all.
If you want to perform background operation, change your method signature to return null + call a "listener" method when data will be ready or return a `Callable<List<myObject>>` and retreive data from it after some other operations done in pararell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink what you're doing.  The new thread will run in parallel with the old one, and may not have an answer ready until the calling thread's got a lot more work done.  You could make the calling thread wait, but why not just call 'anotherInternalMethod' from the main thread?

You could do something like this (but don't!):

```
private void fetchmyObjList(final String abc, final List<myObject>[] retList)  {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                retList = anotherInternalMethod(abc);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
    }).start();
}
```

but the passed retList object (a one-element array) will not get set correctly until some unpredictable time in the future.

Answer (score -2):

This can be solved by the Callable interface in place of Runnable, and retrieving the value with a Future object, which also lets you wait until the value has been computed. You can achieve this with an ExecutorService.